# how to assign an ip address to an ec2 instance using the v2 ruby sdk

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk, elastic-ip

how to assign an ip address to an ec2 instance using the v2 ruby sdk
after the instance has been created.

I tried the

```
ec2.associate_address()
```

method (mentioned in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/developer-guide/ec2-using-elastic-ip-addresses.html) but that seems to be a v1 method

Comment: The change in v2 ruby sdk was the way you construct client like 
`ec2=Aws::EC2::Client.new(
     access_key_id: creds['access_key_id'],
     secret_access_key: creds['secret_access_key']
  )`

Comment: What is the issue you are having when you use that method? Did you allocated the elastic ip as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code in Ruby with aws Ruby SDK v1. I am fetching allocation id of the Elastic IP and passing it to associate_elastic_ip method of instance object.

```
require 'aws-sdk-v1'
require 'json'

temp_ec2 = AWS::EC2.new
instance = temp_ec2.instances["i-8392ld62828f0c97"]
elasticIp = AWS::EC2::ElasticIp.new("49.234.122.12")
if elasticIp.exists?
           begin
                  instance.associate_elastic_ip(elasticIp.allocation_id)
              puts "[Success]EIP has been associated successfully...."
           rescue Exception => e
                  puts "There is an exception in allocating elastic ip and the exception is..#{e}"
           end
else
           puts "[Failed]EIP doesn't exist in the account."
end
```